# CSS/HTML Beginner > i have a div and don't want the html conent image to push the other div away !?

Tags: html, css

So i have a div :

```
.col-4 {
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    margin-bottom:20px;

}
```

and some text a bg image :

```
.head {
    width:300px;
    height:64px;
    background-image: url(images/news_head_bg.png); 

}

.newstext {
        font-size:16px;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px;
    }
```

I want the col-4 to be the main container, the .head is inside and inside it is the .newstext. BUT i also need a picture in there (in html). This is how the html **without** 
the picture looks right now:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headlineprop.css">

</head>

<body>

 <div class="row_1" >
    <div class="col col-4">
    <div class="head">div class="newstext"> 3D Printer for 300 USD </div></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

which gives me exactly what i want - this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL5u7.png

**Here is the problem**

The pink area needs to be a picture from HTML. So if i do this:

```
<body>

 <div class="row_1" >
    <div class="col col-4"><img src="images/content_ohbg.jpg">
    <div class="head"><div class="newstext"> 3D Printer for 300 USD </div></div></div>

</body>
```

it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HMXo.png

So How do i get the image to be content in html but not push the other boxes away?

Comment: Can you please made one fiddle ... Its seems quite complicated as there are so many codes from here http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wE5w6/

Answer (score 1):

Set that picture as background image of pink container which I believe is `.col-4`

```
.col-4 {
    background-image: url(images/content_ohbg.jpg);
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you want the images in `<img>` tag then use :

```
.col-4 {
    position: relative;
} 
.col-4 img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
} 
.head {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: i thought of that too, but the image is changing content. Imagine like a news site and the image is a picture of the article - doing this in css would be crazy i think.

Comment: regarding your edit: i tried that see:

http://jsfiddle.net/wE5w6/2/

still not there :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at relative and absolute positioning in order to place .head on top of the image.

Alternatively, the background image suggestion by Sunrays isn't bad, though you would probably use an inline style for the background-image value (rather than putting it in the style sheet) so that the content can be generated dynamically.

Comment: will relative and absolute give me a problem if i want to go responsive later on?

Comment: It depends on how you have coded it, and what changes with the layout at each breakpoint.  However, that is the same with any code when you make a site responsive.

Answer (score 1):

based on your comment on @Sunrays answer, what you need is absolute positioning.. Without getting into the code, just make your position of `.head` to be absolute with respect to to your parent `.row-1`. Now that its position is absolute, you can force it to be at the top...

**That's fine but what about my changing image?**

Well what we did by the positioning is forced the `.head` to stay at the top, so now when you add the image, it'll cover it.. so you increase the `z-axis` of your `.head`

**What is `z-axis`?**

Just think of it as the vertical axis coming straight out from your computer screen and your setting how far from the screen will the object be on the `z-axis`.. So by setting the value of `z-axis of .head` higher than the image, it'll be over the image..

Comment: so to get it in front i would need a z-axis +1

i tried it over here - didm´t seem to work for me 
http://jsfiddle.net/wE5w6/1/

BUT i love you way of explaining :D

Comment: the value of the `z-axis` can be anything but it has to be greater than that of the `image`

Comment: thank you again for the great explanation about z-axis i totally learned this !

Answer (score 1):

It can be possible as your image will be absolute so it is making your box push down ...

1. You can make your box position absolute or fixed.
2. Or you can make your image relative.

Simply make positions absolute or I say fixed for both div .. means for image and also for box I hope that will work.

---

EDIT in CSS:

```
.col-4 {
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    position: absolute;

}
```

---

EDIT IN HTML

Putting `<div>` first :

```
 <body>

 <div class="row_1" >
 <div class="col col-4">
 <div class="head"><div class="newstext"> 3D Printer for 300 USD </div></div></div>   
 <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Black_square.jpg">


</body>
```

---

RESULT:
[image]

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Shashank_15/4Swpb/

Comment: thats it :D Thankyou so mouch guys!

Comment: i just got +16 for my acc so now i can up you guys too :D so +1 for everyone. thx again

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a "<" before "div class="newstext">". Is that in the question only or ?